# Error Select NODEJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, mysql-workbench

Buenas,

Estoy diseñando una API REST con NODEJS y cuando inserto esta consulta:

```
function getInvTop(req, res) {

                if (connection)
                {

                    connection.query('SELECT recvTimeTs, CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, '+00:00', '+02:00'), fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityType, attrName, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15', function(err, rows) {
                        if(err)
                        {
                            throw err;
                            console.log('Error al Conectar' + error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            res.status(200).json(rows);
                        }
                    });
                }
    }
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
connection.query('SELECT recvTimeTs, CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, '+00:00', '+02:00'), fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityType, attrNa
me, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor2" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15', function(err, rows) {
                                                                                                    ^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

¿Como puedo solucionar este problema?

falla por esto, `CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, '+00:00', '+02:00')`, si lo elimino funciona pero lo necesito para poner la fecha europea.

Esta consulta en MySQL Workbench si funciona.

un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Puede que de error por tas comillas simples de `'+00:00', '+02:00' ` ?

Comment: Buenas, me funciona con comillas dobles. Pero ahora el nombre de la columna cambia a CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, "+00:00", "+02:00"), seria posible ponerla como recvTime? gracias @Aitor

Comment: Vale ya lo he solucionado con un AS muchas gracias.

Comment: Pon lo que hiciste en una respuesta, así si a alguien le pasa lo mismo puede que le sea útil

Comment: Buenas, No me permite añadir una respuesta, esta en estado de espera.

La solución fue esta: SELECT recvTimeTs, CONVERT_TZ(recvTime, "+00:00", "+02:00") AS recvTime, fiwareServicePath, entityId, entityType, attrName, attrType, attrValue, attrMd FROM iof.invjuan WHERE attrName = "sensor1" ORDER BY recvTime DESC LIMIT 15